# how to write !important in @material-ui with useStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a card component using `metrial-ui`. How do I to write `"!important"` using `metrial-ui` and `UseStyles` in react.js? Especially with properties where the value is a number, such as width or height.

To make this more clear, here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { fontSize, textAlign } from '@material-ui/system';
import "../fonts/29LTAzer-Medium.ttf"
import "../Styles/card.css"

const useStyles = makeStyles({

  overrides: {
    MuiCardActions: {
      root: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: "center",
        padding: 8,
        flexDirection: "row-reverse",
      },
    }
  },
  card: {
    width: 700,
    minHeight: 250,
    maxHeight: 250,
    backgroundColor: "#F9F9F9",
    color: "#3599B8 !important",
    borderRadius: 25,
    margin: 15,
    textAlign: 'right',
    fontFamily: "LTAzer-Regular",
  },
  bullet: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    margin: '0 2px',
    transform: 'scale(0.8)',
    fontFamily: "LTAzer-Regular",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#3599B8",
    fontFamily: "LTAzer-Medium",
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
    color: "#3599B8",
    fontFamily: "LTAzer-Regular",
  },
  button: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: "#3599B8",
      border: "solid #3599B8",
    },
    color: "white",
    width: 80,
    marginLeft: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    fontSize: 15,
    border: 3,
    border: "solid #9DCB82",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#9DCB82",
    // paddingRight: 50,
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    fontFamily: "LTAzer-Regular",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  desc: {
    textAlign: "right",
    direction: "rtl",
    fontFamily: "LTAzer-Regular",
    // wordBreak:"break-all",
    // overflowWrap:"break-word",
    whiteSpace: "&nbsp",
    wordWrap: "normal",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    overflow: "hidden",
    display: "-webkit-box",
    // lineHeight:16,
    WebkitLineClamp: 2,
    WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical",
  },
  name: {
    fontFamily: "LTAzer-Medium",
    color: "#3599B8",
  }
});
```

How do I make, for example, the `width: 700`, `!important`?

Comment: Just a side note, usually if you have to use `!important` you're doing something else wrong. I can't help diagnose that however. https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/

Comment: Yeah I agree, I have to use because I'm using more than one templates that each have their own CSS files and rules, later I will try to remove anything that I don't use and fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `number` value to a `string` like `"700px !important"`. Please look at this example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    border: 0,
    width: "200px !important",// has changed to string value
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

[image: Edit magical-johnson-04omf]

Comment: Thank your for the help and edit suggestion